# Sorting by (custom) expression output

Tags: powershell

So I have this as my current code:

```
Get-Process | Sort Valid,ProcessName |
  Format-Table @{n='ProcessName';e={$_.ProcessName}},
    @{n='Valid';e={if(($_.mainmodule.filename | Get-AuthenticodeSignature).Status -eq 'Valid') {1} else {0}}} -AutoSize
```

which gives me an output of:

```
ProcessName            Valid
-----------            -----
3DG4me                     1
Adobe CEF Helper           1
Adobe CEF Helper           1
Adobe Desktop Service      1
AdobeIPCBroker             1
AdobeUpdateService         1
AGSService                 1
ApplicationFrameHost       1
audiodg                    0
avgnt                      1
avguard                    1
Avira.ServiceHost          1
Avira.Systray              1
avshadow                   1
Calculator                 0
CCLibrary                  1
....etc etc
```

Even though I put a sort before I formatted it won't let me sort by Valid, which is an integer. I've tried adding `[int]` before `{1}` and `{0}` but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You sort by `Valid`, although `Valid` in not valid property.

Comment: I mean I put it as name in my calculated property: "@{n='Valid';". I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: How `Sort` should know about what you put after it? `Sort` sort incoming object and incoming objects does not have `Valid` property.

Comment: I fixed it by not using Format-Table at all. I did Get-Process | Select @(whatever) | Sort Valid,ProcessName. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot sort by properties that aren't created until after the sorting happened. `Valid` is not a property of [`System.Diagnostic.Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) objects. If you want to sort by that [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) you need to add it before sorting. This insertion is usually done via `Select-Object`:

```
Get-Process |
  Select-Object ProcessName,
    @{n='Valid';e={if(($_.mainmodule.filename | Get-AuthenticodeSignature).Status -eq 'Valid') {1} else {0}}} |
  Sort Valid, ProcessName |
  Format-Table -AutoSize
```